# How can I give an imageview click effect like a button on Android?

Tags: java, android, button, imageview

I have imageview in my Android app that I am using like a button with the onClick event given, but as you might guess it is not giving imageview a clickable effect when clicked. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can design different images for clicked/not clicked states and set them in the onTouchListener as follows

```
final ImageView v = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.button0);
        v.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
                switch (arg1.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                    v.setImageBitmap(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.img_down));
                    break;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:{
                    v.setImageBitmap(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.img_up));
                    break;
                }
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

The better choice is that you define a selector as follows

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true"   
        android:drawable="@drawable/img_down" />
    <item android:state_selected="false"   
        android:drawable="@drawable/img_up" />
</selector>
```

and select the image in the event:

```
v.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
                v.setSelected(arg1.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: can you explain what res.getDrawable res what it does ?

Comment: v.setSelected will only == true once, immediately moving to false due to MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE. Once the finger is released, then MotionEvent.ACTION_UP occurs. If using the selector method, use separate logic to setSelected or setPressed. if (arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) { v.setPressed(true); } else if (arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) { v.setPressed(false); }

Comment: Better be `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` to keep the image showing as long as we're pressing.

Comment: You don't need to `setOnTouchListener(...`. You can simply create the `<selector ...>` and then set the ImageView clickable in XML like `<ImageView ... android:clickable="true" android:focusable="true" android:src="@drawable/my_selector" />`

Answer (score 80):

You can do this with a single image using something like this:

```
     //get the image view
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView);

    //set the ontouch listener
    imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                    ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
                    //overlay is black with transparency of 0x77 (119)
                    view.getDrawable().setColorFilter(0x77000000,PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                    view.invalidate();
                    break;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
                    ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
                    //clear the overlay
                    view.getDrawable().clearColorFilter();
                    view.invalidate();
                    break;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

I will probably be making this into a subclass of ImageView (or ImageButton as it is also a subclass of ImageView) for easier re-usability, but this should allow you to apply a "selected" look to an imageview.

Comment: I also added a case for ACTION_CANCEL, it works great, thanks!

Comment: Good call - I had added that myself in my own code but will update it here too.

Comment: This may be another question, but how would I cancel after ACTION_UP?

Specifically...
 User hits image.  
 User drags finger off image to cancel.
 But action is not canceled with this code

Comment: I'll also add MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE ;)

Comment: you might want to return `false`, otherwise the view's actual `onClick()` event won't be fired

Comment: Thank you, this helped me resolve my need for button onclick, offclick.

Comment: only worked for me when I changed `return false;` to `return true;`

Comment: Would be nice if you updated the answer since setColorFilter is deprecated!

Comment: Thx so much, this is also working on ShapeableImageView. But any idea if I am using CircleImageView from https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView?

Answer (score 45):

**EDIT**: Although the original answer below works and is easy to set up, refer to [this post](https://plus.google.com/+NickButcher/posts/azEU6s4APbu) by an Android Developer Advocate at Google if you want / need a more efficient implementation. Also note that the [`android:foreground`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html#attr_android:foreground) attribute is [coming to all Views](https://plus.google.com/+NickButcher/posts/dS8Qh7TC8Kq), including ImageView, by default in Android M.

---

The problem with using a selector for an ImageView is that you can only set it as the view's background - as long as your image is opaque, you will not see the selector's effect behind it.

The trick is to wrap your ImageView in a FrameLayout with the attribute [`android:foreground`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html#attr_android:foreground) which allows us to define an *overlay* for its content. If we set [`android:foreground`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html#attr_android:foreground)to a selector (e.g.`?android:attr/selectableItemBackground` for API level 11+) and attach the `OnClickListener` to the FrameLayout instead of the ImageView, the image will be overlaid with our selector's drawable - the click effect we desire!

Behold:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/yourImageFile" />

</FrameLayout>
```

(Note this should be placed within your parent layout.)

```
final View imageButton = findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // do whatever we wish!
    }
});
```

Comment: Great ! This is a very good solution. Same solution used in contacts application for SMS or Call actions.

Comment: Wont work in API < 11. ?android:attr/selectableItemBackground requires API level 11 (current min is 8)

Comment: The `selectableItemBackground` attribute was only added in API level 11, so you must use another selector if you want to use this solution for older API levels. For example, for one of my applications that supports API level 7, I use the `@drawable/list_selector_holo_light` resource generated using the [Android Holo Colors Generator tool](http://android-holo-colors.com/).

Comment: You can achieve the same behavior using only 1 `<ImageButton>` with selectableItemBackground !

Answer (score 30):

Use **style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"** in the XML file. 
It will show the Android default click effect.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
    style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"
/>
```

Comment: This is actually the best answer, a LOT easier

Comment: This sets padding, and even if you set the padding to 0, if the image you give it takes the whole imageView, you won't see any effect of clicking.

Comment: @androiddeveloper use `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` to unset padding.

Comment: It's recommended to use `style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"`: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button#Borderless

Comment: Use `style="?android:actionButtonStyle"` for a clickable ImageView on an ActionBar or ToolBar.

Answer (score 21):

Simply just use an [ImageButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html).

Comment: I personally cannot make it look like ImageView. No border, stretch the image to the size of ImageButton etc. If you can give this border and stretch issue, and update your post. Mine some reputation goes to you as bounty =)

Answer (score 15):

Here is my simple way to solve that:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Agrega porcentajes de cada fraccion de grafica pastel

        Animation animFadein = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.fade_in);

        iv.startAnimation(animFadein);
    });
```

In file `res/anim/fade_in.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:fillAfter="true" >

<alpha
    android:duration="100"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:toAlpha="1.0" />
 </set>
```

Comment: Great solution - thanks! I scrolled through this post trying all the concise ones - and no success. Finally I got here and it worked for me.  One observation - if you have 2+ buttons you want to apply the animation toward .. for my code, I found I need to create a unique instance of Animation object for each button I wanted to apply the effect for.  Reusing the same instance made all the buttons flicker when 1 was clicked.

Answer (score 11):

If you want ripple when tapped, it can be given by this code :

```
<ImageView
    ...
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
    android:clickable="true"
    ...
</ImageView>
```

Similarly, you can implement click effect for TextView

```
<TextView
    ...
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
    android:clickable="true"
    ...
</TextView>
```

Answer (score 9):

Set the selectable background to the ImageView and add some padding. Then attach the `OnClickListener`.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/your_image_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/your_image"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"/>
```

Comment: Is there a way to use it without setting padding, and make the entire ImageView have the effect and not just the empty area?

Comment: This will show ripple in cubic, we need center ripple

Answer (score 8):

For defining the selector drawable choice

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true"   
        android:drawable="@drawable/img_down" />
    <item android:state_selected="false"   
        android:drawable="@drawable/img_up" />
</selector>
```

I have to use android:state_pressed instead of android:state_selected

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed ="true"   
        android:drawable="@drawable/img_down" />
    <item android:state_pressed ="false"   
        android:drawable="@drawable/img_up" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 5):

You could try with `android:background="@android:drawable/list_selector_background"`
to get the same effect as the "Add alarm" in the default "Alarm Clock" (now Desk Clock).

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

```
img.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction())
                {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    {
                        ((ImageView)v).setImageAlpha(200);
                        break;
                    }
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    {
                        // if inside bounds
                        if(event.getX() > 0 && event.getX() < v.getWidth() && event.getY() > 0 && event.getY() < v.getHeight())
                        {
                            ((ImageView)v).setImageAlpha(200);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ((ImageView)v).setImageAlpha(255);
                        }

                        break;
                    }
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    {
                        ((ImageView)v).setImageAlpha(255);
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }

        });
```

@Edit: As Gunhan said there will be backward compatibility problem with setImageAlpha method. 
I used this method:

```
public static void setImageAlpha(ImageView img, int alpha)
    {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 15)
        {
            img.setImageAlpha(alpha);
        }
        else
        {
            img.setAlpha(alpha);
        }
    }
```

Comment: setImageAlpha requires API level 16. Therefore, for backward compatible apps its not possible to use it

Comment: @Gunhan actually, you can use "nineOldAndroids" library which allows using alpha even on older APIs. just use: ViewHelper.setAlpha(view,alpha);

Answer (score 4):

I do some similar things 
See suitable for you or not

View Press Effect Helper:

- usage : do some simple press effect like iOS

  Simple Usage:
- ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
- ViewPressEffectHelper.attach(img)

https://gist.github.com/extralam/7489370

Answer (score 4):

In combination with all the answers above, I wanted the ImageView to be pressed and changed state but if the user moved then "cancel" and not perform an onClickListener.

I ended up making a Point object within the class and setting its coordinates according to when the user pushed down on the ImageView. On the MotionEvent.ACTION_UP I recording a new point and compared the points.

I can only explain it so well, but here is what I did.

```
// set the ontouch listener
weatherView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // Determine what action with a switch statement
        switch (event.getAction()) {

        // User presses down on the ImageView, record the original point
        // and set the color filter
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            ImageView view = (ImageView) v;

            // overlay is black with transparency of 0x77 (119)
            view.getDrawable().setColorFilter(0x77000000,
                    PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
            view.invalidate();

            p = new Point((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());
            break;
        }

        // Once the user releases, record new point then compare the
        // difference, if within a certain range perform onCLick
        // and or otherwise clear the color filter
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
            Point f = new Point((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());
            if ((Math.abs(f.x - p.x) < 15)
                    && ((Math.abs(f.x - p.x) < 15))) {
                view.performClick();
            }
            // clear the overlay
            view.getDrawable().clearColorFilter();
            view.invalidate();
            break;
        }
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

I have an onClickListener set on the imageView, but this can be an method.

Comment: by adding case `MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL` with the same functionality as `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` then it is possible to "clear" the view if the users performs a "drag" which is not a click action.

Answer (score 4):

You can Override `setPressed` in the ImageView and do the color filtering there, instead of creating onTouchEvent listeners:

```
@Override
public void setPressed(boolean pressed) {
    super.setPressed(pressed);

    if(getDrawable() == null)
        return;

    if(pressed) {
        getDrawable().setColorFilter(0x44000000, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        invalidate();
    }
    else {
        getDrawable().clearColorFilter();
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Based on [Mr Zorn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617898/how-can-i-give-an-imageview-click-effect-like-a-button-on-android/14483533#14483533), I use a static method in my abstract Utility class:

```
public abstract class Utility {
...

    public static View.OnTouchListener imgPress(){
        return imgPress(0x77eeddff); //DEFAULT color
    }

    public static View.OnTouchListener imgPress(final int color){
        return new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                switch(event.getAction()) {

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                        ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
                        view.getDrawable().setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                        view.invalidate();
                        break;
                    }

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        v.performClick();

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
                        ImageView view = (ImageView) v;

                        //Clear the overlay
                        view.getDrawable().clearColorFilter();
                        view.invalidate();
                        break;
                    }
                }

                return true;
            }
        };
    }

    ...
}
```

Then I use it with onTouchListener:

```
ImageView img=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) { /* Your click action */ }
});
img_zc.setOnTouchListener(Utility.imgPress()); //Or Utility.imgPress(int_color_with_alpha)
```

It is very simple if you have a lot of images, and you want a simple onTouch effect, without any XML drawable and only one image.

Answer (score 3):

Use an `android.widget.Button`, and set its `background` property to an `android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable`. This can all be done in XML, or programmatically. See the [Custom Button section of the Form Stuff tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html#CustomButton).

Answer (score 3):

I create sample [here](https://github.com/thanhbinh84/clickable-image-view), just change ImageView into [ClickableImageView](https://github.com/thanhbinh84/clickable-image-view/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/thanhbinh84/clickableimageviewsample/ClickableImageView.java) from your layout. Hope it help.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think ImageButton is a better solution

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="96dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:foreground="@drawable/selector" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a more beauty solution if you use background images :)

```
public static void blackButton(View button){
    button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                    v.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xf0f47521,PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                    v.invalidate();
                    break;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                    v.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
                    v.invalidate();
                    break;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution, which, using "[**nineOldAndroids**](http://nineoldandroids.com/)" library, supports old APIs too:

```
rootView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(final View v, final MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listview_normal);
                ViewHelper.setAlpha(imageView, 1);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                v.setBackgroundResource(0);
                v.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.listview_pressed));
                ViewHelper.setAlpha(imageView, 0.75f);
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

It assumes the rootView is the cell itself (the layout), and that it has a single imageView that you wish to be affected by the color that you wish to apply to the whole cell.

---

EDIT: if you wish, you can also extend ImageView to handle foreground, and set it to "?android:attr/selectableItemBackground". There is a library for this [**here**](https://github.com/baole/ForegroundView) and a tutorial on how to do it for any view you wish, [**here**](http://antoine-merle.com/blog/2013/07/17/adding-a-foreground-selector-to-a-view/).

Comment: @madlymad thank you for fixing the code formatting, though I think something went wrong with indentation. Anyway, it's good enough to be able to read it...

Answer (score 2):

OR:

You can use this form, with Image Button.

Create file `res/drawable/btn_video.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ico2"
        android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ico2" />
</selector>
```

And `res/layout/activity_main.xml`:

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:onClick="eventImageBtn"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_video"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
/>
```

Your image change with a click, and you can adjust with a linear layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/menu_item_background">

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical"
                      android:paddingLeft="@dimen/main_screen_side_padding" android:paddingRight="@dimen/main_screen_side_padding" android:paddingTop="@dimen/main_screen_side_padding" android:paddingBottom="@dimen/main_screen_side_padding"
                      android:background="#ffb3ff13" android:weightSum="10.00">


            <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="2.50" android:background="#ff56cfcd" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dp" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:onClick="eventImageBtn"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_video"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="0.50" android:layout_height="0dp" android:background="#ffffffff" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="4.50" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dp" android:background="#ff8aa5ff">
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="0.50" android:layout_height="0dp" android:background="#ffffffff" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="2.00" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dp" android:background="#ffff7d1a" >
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help on this thread. However, you missed one thing...you need to handle the ACTION_CANCEL as well. If you don't then you might not properly restore the alpha value of the ImageView in the event that a parent view in the view hierarchy intercepts a touch event (think a ScrollView wrapping you ImageView).

Here is a complete class that is based off the above class but takes care of the ACTION_CANCEL as well. It uses an ImageViewCompat helper class to abstract the differences in the pre-post JellyBean API.

```
public class ChangeAlphaOnPressedTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

    private final float pressedAlpha;

    public ChangeAlphaOnPressedTouchListener(float pressedAlpha) {
        this.pressedAlpha = pressedAlpha;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) v;
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            ImageViewCompat.setAlpha(iv, pressedAlpha);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (isInsideViewBounds(v, event)) {
                ImageViewCompat.setAlpha(iv, pressedAlpha);
            } else {
                ImageViewCompat.setAlpha(iv, 1f);
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            ImageViewCompat.setAlpha(iv, 1f);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            ImageViewCompat.setAlpha(iv, 1f);
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static boolean isInsideViewBounds(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return event.getX() > 0 && event.getX() < v.getWidth() && event.getY() > 0
                && event.getY() < v.getHeight();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code. The idea is that ImageView gets color filter when user touches it, and color filter is removed when user stops touching it.

Martin Booka Weser, András, Ah Lam, altosh,  solution doesn't work when ImageView has also onClickEvent.
worawee.s and kcoppock (with ImageButton) solution requires background, which has no sense when ImageView is not transparent.

This one is extension of [AZ_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7754032/185022) idea about color filter.

```
class PressedEffectStateListDrawable extends StateListDrawable {

    private int selectionColor;

    public PressedEffectStateListDrawable(Drawable drawable, int selectionColor) {
        super();
        this.selectionColor = selectionColor;
        addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed }, drawable);
        addState(new int[] {}, drawable);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onStateChange(int[] states) {
        boolean isStatePressedInArray = false;
        for (int state : states) {
            if (state == android.R.attr.state_pressed) {
                isStatePressedInArray = true;
            }
        }
        if (isStatePressedInArray) {
            super.setColorFilter(selectionColor, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        } else {
            super.clearColorFilter();
        }
        return super.onStateChange(states);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isStateful() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

usage:

```
Drawable drawable = new FastBitmapDrawable(bm);
imageView.setImageDrawable(new PressedEffectStateListDrawable(drawable, 0xFF33b5e5));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is creating a new XML file. In this case, let's call it "example.xml" in the drawable folder, and put in the follow code:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/blue"
          android:state_pressed="true" />

</selector>
```

But before that you have to set the colors in the colors.xml file, in the values folder, like this:

```
<resources>
    <color name="blue">#0000FF</color>
</resources>
```

That made, you just set the Button / ImageButton to use the new layout, like this:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/example"
/>
```

Then when you click that image, it will change to the color set in

```
<item android:drawable="@color/blue"
      android:state_pressed="true" />
```

giving the feedback that you want...

Answer (score 1):

I tried with:

```
<ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/get_started"
        android:src="@drawable/home_started"
        style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:longClickable="true" />
```

and this worked. Please note on the line: `style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"`

Comment: This doesn't work in the case of 0 padding and the image takes entire area of the view.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution I ever seen. Its more generic.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:fillAfter="true" >

    <alpha
        android:duration="100"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />
</set>
```

Comment: In which place and file it should be injected?

Answer (score 0):

You can made a simple ripple effect for `ImageView`. This is great for icons.

In `res/drawable` create `circular_shape.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item>
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
```

In `res/drawable` create a drawable res file `ripple_effect_iv.xml`:

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:color="?attr/colorControlHighlight">

 <item
    android:id="@android:id/mask"
    android:drawable="@drawable/circular_shape" />

</ripple>
```

Set it as `background` for `ImageView` also you can consider `padding` for showing ripple natural:

```
     <ImageView
        android:background="@drawable/ripple_effect_iv"
        android:padding="10dp"/>
```

yes your `ImageView` become small but you can simply increase the `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height`.

Answer (score -1):

As for now, we should develop [Material Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_Design) practice. In this case you could add a ripple effect on an ImageView.