# How do you create a Hotspots on an ImageView

Tags: android

I want to create clickable/hotspots on an imageview that when clicked trigger an animation.  I have read on several post's that creating "hotspots" on an ImageView is the way to accomplish this but I have not found any working examples that show how it is done.  Can someone please provide a small example of how to create a hotspot on an Imageview?

Not sure if this has any impact on the design but the images are going to be in an PagerAdapter so the image names will change when the user swipes into the next page.

Comment: is this what you mean? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617898/how-can-i-give-imageview-click-effect-like-a-button-in-android

Comment: Not exactly, I do not want the entire image to be clickable only certain areas of the image.   The image I have is a image of a calendar.  When a user clicks on a specific region of the calendar It will trigger an animation that expands and collapses.  There will only be a few clickable  areas on the image.

Comment: how about this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961071/android-how-to-make-a-clickable-map-image-with-each-country-producing-a-differe

Comment: Check answer on [Android: how to make a clickable map image with each country producing a different action?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961071/android-how-to-make-a-clickable-map-image-with-each-country-producing-a-differe).