# Click on image do not respond on first time, need to click it again, Why?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-xml

**This is XML file code piece:**

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivh4c5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/logoutmenu" />
```

**This is code piece:**

```
    logOut.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            final SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("ProfileName", MODE_PRIVATE);
            Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.clear();
            editor.commit();

            finish();
        }});
```

**Result:**

On clicking logout image application must logout (only on first time).

**Problem:**

Clicking on logout image do not respond on first click , I have to click it again in order to logout from application.

Please provide corrected code.

Comment: I can not use image button, i have to use image only.

Comment: Then look for other  posts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617898/how-can-i-give-imageview-click-effect-like-a-button-in-android this question is redoundant

Comment: Link you provide is not the answer of my question, I dont want to change image, i just want to respond it on first click.

Comment: It should respond on first click so i invited you to look to other post to see other methods to make an image clickable. When you can't make your method work sometimes it is a good idea to look at other's

Answer (score 2):

use this only

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivh4c5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/logoutmenu" />
```

Answer (score 2):

With your xml code you are focusing the `ImageView` in the first click and calling `onClick` with the second click.

You should put  `android:focusable="false" android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` (or remove the lines) to respond on first click.

If you want the image could be focusable and respond to first click you can check: [onFocusChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnFocusChangeListener%28android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener%29)

Answer (score 0):

by clicking a focusable ImageView, OnFocusChangeListener() gets called. you can get the event like this:

```
logOut.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    if(hasFocus){
            final SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("ProfileName", MODE_PRIVATE);
            Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.clear();
            editor.commit();

            finish();
    }
    }
   }
});
```