# How to Implement onClick and onTouch in Button?

Tags: android, button, touch-event

i have one button Create in programmatically i need to implement Both onClick and OnTouch to That Button in same time i want implement button `focus_change`.

Am implemented like this

```
ImageView Settings_Button = new ImageView(this);       
        Settings_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {    
                //UtilityClass.focusOnallviews(view);
                Intent newIntent = new Intent(activity.getBaseContext(), ProfileSettingActivity.class);
                activity.startActivity(newIntent);           
            }
        });
```

`Note`: i want implement `state_focused` and `state_pressed` when i interact with button how can solve this issue.

Comment: Check this 1:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617898/how-can-i-give-imageview-click-effect-like-a-button-in-android

Comment: why you want to add ontouch and on click event?

Answer (score 1):

You can use OnTouch event

```
ImageView Settings_Button = new ImageView(this);       
Settings_Button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
        switch(arg1.getAction()){
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                     // Button is pressed. Change the button to pressed state here
                break;

          case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                     // Button is being touched and swiped
                break;

          case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                     // Button is released. Change the button to unpressed state here.
                    Intent newIntent = new Intent(activity.getBaseContext(),ProfileSettingActivity.class);
                    activity.startActivity(newIntent);     
                break;

        }
       });
```