# Adding background to button breaks sizing

Tags: android, button, layout, imagebutton

I have an icon I would like to scale down to 48dp and use as a button (no background). However, adding the `android:background` attribute (to make the background transparent) seems to break the sizing I have applied to the button and it displays at its full size:

[image]

Desired size but with ugly background:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/composition_send"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_send_black_48dp"/>
```

Full (wrong) size, but with no background (desired):

```
<ImageButton
    ...
    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"/>
```

Why does adding that one line ruin the sizing?

Comment: add `style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"` instead of `android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"` may be it will help.

Answer (score 0):

When you don't set the background property for the `Imagebutton`, the `Imagebutton` will use the default `Imagebutton` background of Android. And this background contains the padding so your image is smaller.
So when you set the background for `Imagebutton` by a color or resource that doesn't contain padding, your image will look larger

You can find the default background of the `Imagebutton` and another `View` in

> ..\Android\sdk\platforms\android-23\data\res\drawable\

(Some resource in this is not public)

For example
If you compile your project with API 23, the default background of `ImageButton` is `btn_default_material`

```
    <ImageButton
        ...
        android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default_material"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_send_black_48dp"/>

    <ImageButton
        ...
        android:src="@drawable/ic_send_black_48dp"/>
```

So you set the `android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default_material"` or don't use background property, 2 `ImageButton` will look same (note: `btn_default_material` is not public for use)

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

try to add

```
        android:src="@drawable/ic_send_black_48dp
        android:backgroundTint="#0000"
```

to ImageButton, it will make the background transparent and then you can set the image on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want that ugly background in imagebutton,then you can use an imageview as button and set onClickListener on it. It will behave like a button.
This [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617898/how-can-i-give-imageview-click-effect-like-a-button-in-android) will be helpful to you.