# Enable press effect on RecyclerView's item in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have RecyclerView with list of data:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/categoriesList"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"/>
```

When I tap to any items in this list, I wait pressing effect. I do not have a click handler, but in the standard ListView, any click on an element is visible. And I look like there's nothing to react

I need next:

[image]

Comment: you can try with elevation when tapping items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add these lines to your single row layout instead of recyclerview tag.

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your answer: [How can I give an imageview click effect like a button on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617898/how-can-i-give-an-imageview-click-effect-like-a-button-on-android)

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true"   
        android:drawable="@drawable/img_down" />
    <item android:state_selected="false"   
        android:drawable="@drawable/img_up" />
</selector>
```

> You can customized it and use it as per your choice of colour.